# Is there an existing way to import EDF files into R?

Tags: r, european-data-format

I have some [European Data Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Data_Format) (EDF) files that I would like to import into R.

There are some Python libraries for parsing EDF files and the EDF spec is available, so I know it's possible, but I would avoid writing code if I could.

Does there already exist a facility for importing these kinds of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried look for the same thing a while ago, but I couldn't find anything for R. I ended up using [biosig](http://biosig.sourceforge.net/download.html) Python module to convert edfs to ascii. There is also this [edf2ascii](http://www.teuniz.net/edf2ascii/)-converter.

Answer (score 4):

1. Was looking for the same thing. Found this function written by Fabien Feschet - works well for my data. http://feschet.fr/?p=11
2. Found another resource recently. This works very well. Need to download both read_edf.R and utilities.R
   https://github.com/bwrc/edf/tree/master/R

Answer (score 1):

I guess there wasn't any package available at the time when the question was asked but now you could use **edfReader**:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edfReader/

https://github.com/Pisca46/edfReader